# How to redirect without the default Accept header?

Tags: javascript, html, http, browser, download

I am developing a web app which relies on the client's `Accept` header. When negotiating the content type my server prefers `text/plain` over `text/html`.

I want to add a download button to the HTML page which redirects to the page currently being viewed. This time requesting a `text/plain` variant; the server will set the `Content-Disposition` header, initiating a download.

The problem is that e.g. Firefox completely ignores the `type` attribute on links which is supposed to do just that. *Example:*

```html
<a href=/ type=text/plain>Download</a>
```

```
GET /
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
GET /
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

The last request is from clicking the download link and there is no `text/plain` there.

I've managed to create a workaround with JavaScript but it's ugly at best:

```html
<a id=download download href=#>Download</a>
<script>
  document.getElementById("download").onclick = 
    async () => {
      // send the request manually instead of redirecting directly
      const res = await fetch(window.location, { headers: { "Accept": "text/plain" } });
      const text = await res.text();

      // redirect to the file in memory
      const file = new File([text], "hello.txt", { type: "application/octet-stream" });
      window.location.assign(window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
    };
</script>
```

**This can't be the final solution, there has to be a better way!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mistaken about what the `type` attribute is supposed to do.

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> The rel, rev, hreflang, and type attributes may be used to indicate to the user the likely nature of the target resource before the user follows the link.

It tells the browser to **expect** plain text, not to prefer it in the `Accept` header.

---

HTML provides no mechanism to control the `Accept` header. The traditional approach to this problem is to use different URLs.

For example:

- `http://example.com/example.html` for HTML
- `http://example.com/example.txt` for plain text
- `http://example.com/example` for content negotiated data

Apache HTTP has a [MultiViews directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) for handling this.